# how to get django pagination unique item id across all pages?

Tags: django, pagination

I am learning how to implement django pagination.
I want to let user save all changes (the whole form no matter which pagination )when he/she clicks the save-all button. However, when using **forloop.counter0**, the django will render duplicate forloop counter.
How can I generate continuous unique id from 0 to n-1 so that at views.py, the views can recognize every items? Thanks!

```
{% for thing in things %}
    <tr id="tr-{{ thing.id }}">
        <td style="display:none"><input type="text" name="hidden-id-{{ forloop.counter0 }}" value="{{ thing.id }}"></td>

    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Is there existing any methods like plussing the pagecounter and the forloop counter?

Comment: I am trying to use {{ things.start_index }};hope this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trials-and-errors:
I've found that django by default (or maybe always) don't let us save things across all page(pagination).
To generate unique IDs across all pages, we can use the **|add** filter together with the start_index attribute which is autogenerated by django.

```
 {% for thing in things %}
          <tr id="tr-{{ thing.id }}">
            <td style="display:none"><input type="text" name="hidden-id-{{ things.start_index |add:forloop.counter0 }}"  value="{{ thing.id }}"></td>
          </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```